# Как объединить массивы которые в нижнем регистре

Tags: javascript, массивы, регулярные-выражения

криво настроен slize

есть масив

```
 var myAtrr= [
     " Гепатопротекторы",
     " Ненасыщенные жирные кислоты и пр. липиды",
     " Парафармацевтики",
     " Нутрицевтики",
     " Аллергия",
     " Атеросклероз",
     " Детоксикация",
     " очищение организма",
     " Нормализация обмена веществ",
     " Снижение холестерина",
     " предупреждение атеросклероза",
     " Атопический дерматит",
     " Гепатит хронический",
     " Инсульт",
     " нарушение мозгового кровообращения",
     " Миома матки",
     " Улучшение работы печени и желчного пузыря",
     " Пищеварительная",
     " Сердечно-сосудистая",
     " Обмен веществ",
     " Взрослым",
     " Очищение организма"
   ];
```

нужно как-то задать проверку на регистр следующего элемента массива за индексом чтоб вышло вместо

```
     " Атеросклероз",`
     " Детоксикация",
     " очищение организма",
     " Нормализация обмена веществ",
```

вышло

```
     " Атеросклероз",
     " Детоксикация, очищение организма",
```

пробовал регулярными выражениями сломал голову ничего не получается

Answer (score 1):

проходите по массиву в с с конца. если элемент с мелкой буквы, то присоединяете к предыдущему и удаляете. вроде все просто.

```js
var myAtrr= [
  " Гепатопротекторы",
  " Ненасыщенные жирные кислоты и пр. липиды",
  " Парафармацевтики",
  " Нутрицевтики",
  " Аллергия",
  " Атеросклероз",
  " Детоксикация",
  " очищение организма",
  " Нормализация обмена веществ",
  " Снижение холестерина",
  " предупреждение атеросклероза",
  " Атопический дерматит",
  " Гепатит хронический",
  " Инсульт",
  " нарушение мозгового кровообращения",
  " Миома матки",
  " Улучшение работы печени и желчного пузыря",
  " Пищеварительная",
  " Сердечно-сосудистая",
  " Обмен веществ",
  " Взрослым",
  " Очищение организма"
];

for(i=myAtrr.length -1; i>=0; i--){
   if(/^\s*[а-я]/.test(myAtrr[i])){
      myAtrr[i-1] += ',' + myAtrr[i];
      myAtrr.splice(i,1);
   }    
}

console.log(myAtrr);
```